# Copy a cell contents inc background from one sheet to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a master records sheet with a list of names.
These names are all copied from absolute values in 10 other individual group sheets using formulae like;
='C3'!A19

Sheet names are;
Master Sheet, A1, A2, B1, B2 .....

The values are copied, but the formatting of the cell background colour hasn't copied over and I don't have VB code experience. I've tried a few pieces of code, but can't get them to work as I want after playing with it.

Because the names are taken from one sheet and do not line up exactly in the master record (other than the A1 sheet) I've tried using the IF(MATCH function but can't get it to work correctly. I've also managed to get it to work using the format painter tool - but that only works as a one off - and the group name colours change from day to day.

Open to any suggestions :)

Can this be done without using VBA \ Macros i.e. a formula only?

Comment: formulas cannot copy formatting

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need a macro.

This will work for REALLY SIMPLE formulas like:

```
 ='C3'!A19
```

It will **not** work for formulas like:

```
 ='C3'!A19+1
```

Put the following macro in a standard module:

```
Sub KopyFormat()
    Dim cell As Range, sourze As Range, s As String

    For Each cell In Selection
        If cell.HasFormula Then
            s = Mid(cell.Formula, 2)
            Set sourze = Range(s)
            sourze.Copy
            cell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Then select the formula cells you wish to process and run the macro.

Macros are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the macro from the Excel window:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**